# WCF, NetTcpBinding, Streamed transfer mode can be duplex?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm  uses NetTcpBinding with Streamed TransferMode. Now I tried to achieve a callback as duplex but I got error message. It is possible to use NetTcpBinding with Streamed TransferMode and use (duplex) callback service contract? 
The background:
- I use NetTcpBinding because it is fast and there's no nat issue
- I use streamed mode because I tranfers big files as well.

the config:

```
 <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="DuplexBinding" transferMode="Streamed"
                closeTimeout="00:10:00"  openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"  transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="104857600" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600"
             >
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="104857600" maxStringContentLength="104857600" maxArrayLength="104857600" maxBytesPerRead="104857600" maxNameTableCharCount="104857600"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"/>
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

the contract:

```
IMyDataService.cs

   [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(INotifyCallback))]
    public interface IMyDataService
    {
        [OperationContract(ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None)]
        [FaultContract(typeof(MyFaultException))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(MyUserAlreadyLoggedInFaultException))]
        [FaultContract(typeof(AuthorizationFaultException))]
        Guid Authenticate(Guid clientID, string userName, string password, bool forceLogin);
    }


INotifyCallback.cs

    public interface INotifyCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void ShowMessageBox(string message);
    }
```

i have get error whent set transferMode="Streamed"

> Contract requires Duplex, but Binding 'NetTcpBinding' doesn't support
>   it or isn't configured properly to support it.

everyone can suggest thanks

Comment: Are you using a DuplexChannelFactory to connect to the server (or just a ChannelFactory)?

Comment: i use IMetadataExchange to add servicereferece and create client proxy

Answer (score 1):

In your client code, make sure you're using [DuplexChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576164%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to create the channel to the server:

```
INotifyCallback callbackObject = new NotifyCallbackImpl(); //your concrete callback class
var channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IMyDataServce>(callbackObject); //pick your favourite constructor!
IMyDataService channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
try {
    var guid = channel.Authenticate(....);
    //... use guid...
} finally {
    try {
        channel.Close();
    } catch (Exception) {
        channel.Abort();
    }
}
```

[Edit] The proxy of an auto-generated service reference should extend [DuplexClientBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576169%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: you are misunderstand my question. my problem is current server not run with config when i set attribute transferMode="Streamed", if is remove it server run but i want use large file upload should transferMode="Streamed" is good choose

Comment: yes, with config atrribute transferMode="Streamed", default it set transferMode="Buffer" but in my case use with dublex it problems

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005020/nettcpbinding-with-streaming-and-session) mentions some of the issues with ordered messages, callbacks, and streaming. (Pick any two of those and it would work--not all three at the same time). With streaming enabled, the duplex channel won't work. Sorry.

Comment: Possible work-arounds include: using two separate contracts/channels (one streaming, one not) and/or refactoring out the callback.

Comment: you are suggest to detail more? that is great suggest.

Comment: All-in-all, it's probably not going to be an issue to go with Buffered. Run it, profile it, and if memory is an issue *and you know it's caused by buffering*, then you could try to implement something more complex. I'd stick with Buffered transfer mode for now, though.

Comment: i do something with asynchronous to upload file.